# Proving the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$a_n \geq 0$

I need to prove the following:

$\sum{a_n}$ converges if and only if $\sum{\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}}$ converges.

I have proved it in one direction (left to right), but I'm stuck with the other direction.
I tried starting with $\frac{a_n}{1+a_n} \leq a_n$, therefore, $a_n \leq \frac{1+a_n}{a_n} \leq \frac{1+a_n}{a^3_n} = \frac{1}{a^3_n} + \frac{1}{a^2_n}$.

Both these terms are convergent ($p$ series with $p >1$), so their sum is convergent. $a_n$ is less than a convergent sequence therefore the $\sum{a_n}$ is convergent.

I think there's someway I can use the comparison test, but is this in any way correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{1 + a_n}$ converges, there exists some $N$ such that for $n \geq N$, $\frac{a_n}{1 + a_n} < \frac{1}{2}$. From this we get:

$$2a_n < 1 + a_n$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n < 1$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n + 1 < 2$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{a_n + 1} > \frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a_n}{a_n + 1} \geq \frac{a_n}{2}$$

So by the comparison test, $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{2}$ converges, and so also $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_n$ does.

Comment: Very neat, concise and simple answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that
$a_n \ge 0$.

If
$\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
< c
$
where $0 < c < \frac12$,
then
$a_n < c(1+a_n)
$
or
$a_n(1-c) < c$
or
$a_n 
< \frac{c}{1-c}
< 2c
$.

Since
$\sum \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
$
 converges,
for any $c > 0$
there is a $n(c)$
such that
$\sum_{n \ge n(c)} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
< c
$.

Therefore,
for any $0 < c < \frac12$.
there is a $n(c)$
such that
$\sum_{n \ge n(c)} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}
< c
$.
Since
$a_n 
< 2c
$
for all such $c$,
$\sum_{n \ge n(c)} a_n
< 2c
$,
so the sum converges.

Comment: it's clearer now, thank you very much